# Haskell function to explode a list

Tags: haskell

I've written the following `explode` function using `break`. The intended behavior is, that a list is divided into sublists by a predicate function, i.e. those elements which match the predicate are the separators - no empty lists should be returned.

Here are some examples:

```
explode id [True, True, False] = [[False]]
explode id [False, True, False] = [[False], [False]]
explode undefined [] = []
explode id [False, False, True, False] = [[False, False], [False]]
explode (\x -> mod x 3 == 0) [0..10] = [[1,2],[4,5],[7,8],[10]]
```

The signature of this function is:

```
explode :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Here is the implementation:

```
explode _ [] = []
explode f xs
    | null zs = [z]
    | null z  = explode f (tail zs)
    | True    = z : explode f (tail zs)
        where (z, zs) = break f xs
```

Is there a better way to do this, a maybe more haskell-idiomatic one? Also, what is the complexity of such a function? I believe the running time is linear, but what about the space complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like blufox' solution, but remember you can replace explicit recursion by a fold, too:

```
explode f xs = filter (not.null) $ foldr go [[]] xs where 
  go x (xs:xss) = if f x then []:xs:xss else (x:xs):xss
```

Comment: I don't like this solution due to the use of foldr. Testing with a very large list (like [1..1000000]) results in a stack overflow, whereas my solution does not. Also it is not faster in cases where it successfully computes the result. Of course I like the beauty of the code, but it's simply not more efficient or correct as my own version - so what is the advantage of this version?

Comment: @scravy In his favor, you did ask for a Haskell-idiomatic solution. This solution is one such. See my other explanation for why it is idiomatic.

Comment: @scravy If it's not library code or so, readability is usually more important than anything else. I wouldn't care for the 1000000 elememts case until I really encounter such a list and actually *have* a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

grouping list separated by some values intuitively seems like a group by operation. That is, abc,def,ghi => (abc)(def)(ghi)
So groupBy seems more intuitive for me, and it results in more concise code.

```
import Data.List

explode fn = filter (nfn . head) . gb
  where nfn = not . fn
        gb = groupBy ((. nfn) . (&&) . nfn)
```

If you cann't tolerate pointfree, here is the alternate definition for gb

```
gb = groupBy (\x y -> nfn x && nfn y)
```

Comment: I can `tolerate` pointfree ;-) - but why should I use this solution at all? I can't see where this code is better to read (= easier to maintain?) or has a better performance (testing shows no difference between my solution and yours). I had a look into the GHC libraries since `explode (== ' ')` should be the same as `words`, which is implemented in a rather “ugly” way - reminding me of my own explode function (also using `break`). So (no offense, I'm curious) why do you guys keep telling me about alternative solutions instead of criticizing my code or explaining in what way these are better?

Comment: (reached the maximum length of a comment: here's the link to the words-function in GHC.Base http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#words )

Comment: Because Nature abhors a naked recursion :) ... Seriously, using the fold,map,filter trinity is one of the hallmarks of good functional code. See [Real World Haksell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html) the section "Why use folds maps and filters". This almost a given in the community that it is forgotten to explain it explicitly. Another tenet is to use the API where possible rather than inventing your own wheel. Here, I believe that your operation is a special groupBy, which is why I gave this solution.

Comment: A final point in their favor is that these higher order operations restrict the behavior, and provide assurances about their interface. That is, a filter never produces lists whose length is greater than given. A map always returns lists which are equal in magnitude, and fold captures the linear decomposition of the problem. So unless your solution has a good reason to use explicit recursion, you might expect these to be the first suggestions :). OTOH, this seems to be a good question you could ask to S.O